# How can I check whether the numbers in the array list are sequential

Tags: java, arraylist

I want to check if numbers in an arraylist are sequential. The number in array start with 1, and for the next should be 2, 3, and 4. This means that every next element is 1 larger than the previous.

```
public static void main(String[]args){
    ArrayList<Integer> array = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    array.add(1); array.add(3);
    for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++){
        if(logic here){
            System.out.println(not sequence);
        }else{
            system.out.pritnln(sequence);
        }
    }
}
```

For this case, after 1 it should be 2, but there is 3. how can i implement the correct logic for this case? Thank you!!!

Comment: go for LinkedList

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/322715/when-to-use-linkedlist-over-arraylist-in-java will help

Comment: Update you if statement (LOGIC HERE) with following statement,
if( (i + 1) == array[i])

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter number of elements: ");
int input = sc.nextInt();
List<Integer> al = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            
// Store elements into arraylist
for(int i=0; i<input; i++)
    al.add(sc.nextInt());
            
boolean isSequential = IntStream.range(1, al.size()).allMatch(value -> al.get(value) - al.get(value - 1) == 1);
System.out.println(isSequential ? "Sequential" : "Not Sequential");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just walk down the array once, checking for a delta of some value other than 1:

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(new Integer[] {1, 2, 3, 5});
for (int i=1; i < list.size(); ++i) {
    if (list.get(i) - list.get(i-1) != 1) {
        System.out.println("out of sequence");
        break;
    }
}
```

This prints:

```
1
2
3
out of sequence
```

Comment: for this case, you already have element in an arraylist. what if the elements in the array are obtained from user input? in case arraylist is empty, and when user input some number, the number will stored in arraylist. Thank you for your answer :)

Comment: Store user input in two variables and apply the same logic mentioned here.

Answer (score 0):

Simple one-liner, you can use an IntStream range to match the elements:

```
List<Integer> list = List.of(1, 2, 3);
boolean isSequential = IntStream.range(0, list.size())
        .allMatch(value -> value + 1 == list.get(value));
System.out.println(isSequential);
```

Comment: If you start from 2 i.e. 2 3 4 then it will fail.

Comment: @NitinBisht the OP specifically said "_The number in array start with 1_"